# Update panel html in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I have a code written in Extjs with HTML and i want to refresh the frame after changing the value. Here is my code:

```
xtype: 'panel',
                    region: 'center',
                    split: true,
                    itemId: 'contentPanel',
                    name: 'contentPanel',
                    title: 'Ultimele anunțuri',
                    html:'<iframe src="' + this.linkpanel + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>'
```

but when i change **linkpanel**, frame show same page :(

Comment: This is not enough code, who's setting `linkpanel`? Are you recreating the object after changing `linkpanel`. If you want to make it easier for others to help, you should always create a reduction of the problem. https://fiddle.sencha.com

Comment: linkpanel is a variable and when i press a button linkpanel is changed. but frame is not changed.

Comment: Your comment is still not very helpful, code that reproduces the problem is more helpful. From your comment, it looks like you would need to regenerate your widget so that your variable change applies to anything. Again... without code that is runnable, it's hard to help

Comment: here is the code http://pastebin.com/wuFrUFkV

Comment: That code does not attempt to change `linkpanel` anywhere

Comment: i tried handler:function()
          '{
          linkpanel = "index.php";
          //panel.doLayout();
          }' but dont work

Comment: Alex, if you can't post an example that I can run, and your example is full of missing references, you can't really expect others to help you. I am telling you for the third time. Create an example of your problem that runs and we can observe the problem https://fiddle.sencha.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you want to update a panel, you can just call

```
panel.update('<iframe></iframe>');
```

In your case you don't need to update the whole HTML, you can just update the src of the iframe

```
handler:function() {
    me.down('#contentPanel').getEl().down('iframe', true).src = "http://google.com";
}
```

See https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/705. You won't see anything load into the iframe because it's from a different server, but it will work fine when you run it on your own server

Comment: @Alex Dang it man, your fiddle has errors. You are being careless and I'm trying to help you

Comment: i can run on my apache server. here is the code http://www.fileshare.ro/e30641901

Comment: @Alex I've posted a link to a running example.